# MySql LEFT OUTER JOIN causing duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, join

Im running a query to grab the first 10 `profiles (think of them as an article that shows when a shop opens and holds information about that shop)`. I'm using the `OUTER JOIN` to `select * images that belong to the profile PK`.

Im running the following query, the main part I'm trying to focus on is the `JOIN`. I won't post the whole query as it's just a whole bunch of `'table'.'colname' = 'table.colname'`.

But here is where the magic happens during my outer join.

```
LEFT JOIN `content_image` AS `image` ON `profile`.`content_ptr_id` = `image`.`content_id`
```

#### Full Query:

I've formatted like this so everyone can see the query without scrolling endlessly to the right.

```
select `profile`.`content_ptr_id` AS `profile.content_ptr_id`,
       `profile`.`body` AS `profile.body`,
       `profile`.`web_site` AS `profile.web_site`,
       `profile`.`email` AS `profile.email`,
       `profile`.`hours` AS `profile.hours`,
       `profile`.`price_range` AS `profile.price_range`,
       `profile`.`price_range_high` AS `profile.price_range_high`,
       `profile`.`primary_category_id` AS `profile.primary_category_id`,
       `profile`.`business_contact_email` AS `profile.business_contact_email`,
       `profile`.`business_contact_phone` AS `profile.business_contact_phone`,
       `profile`.`show_in_directory` AS `profile.show_in_directory`,
       `image`.`id` AS `image.id`,
       `image`.`content_id` AS `image.content_id`,
       `image`.`type` AS `image.type`,
       `image`.`order` AS `image.order`,
       `image`.`caption` AS `image.caption`,
       `image`.`author_id` AS `image.author_id`,
       `image`.`image` AS `image.image`,
       `image`.`link_url` AS `image.link_url`
FROM content_profile AS profile
LEFT JOIN `content_image` AS `image` ON `profile`.`content_ptr_id` = `image`.`content_id`
GROUP BY profile.content_ptr_id
LIMIT 10, 12
```

Is there  a way I can group my results per profile? E.g all images will show in the one profile result? I can't use **group by** as I'm getting an error

```
Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #12 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'broadsheet.image.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by]
  code: 'ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP',
  errno: 1055,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
```

Is there a possible way around this `group by` error or another query I could run?

### Tables:

#### content_image

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| order      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| caption    | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| author_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| image      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| link_url   | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

#### content_profile

```
+------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| content_ptr_id         | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| body                   | longtext             | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| web_site               | varchar(200)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email                  | varchar(75)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| menu                   | longtext             | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hours                  | longtext             | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| price_range            | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| price_range_high       | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| primary_category_id    | int(11)              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| business_contact_name  | varchar(255)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| business_contact_email | varchar(75)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| business_contact_phone | varchar(20)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| show_in_directory      | tinyint(1)           | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: This is a bad question IMO.  You didn't even show us the actual query in question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ill add it in.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I didn't add it in initially because I thought it may not be needed? Added it in anyway. If the question isn't clear enough let me know!

Comment: `content_image.content_id` is not unique. It is to be expected that left joining with `content_image` by `content_id` creates duplicates (one for each `content_image` with the same `content_id`).

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister is there a solution to this?

Comment: What do you want to do when you have a profile with more than one image? Which image do you want to select? The latest? Any?

Comment: Well I want to select * images for that one profile and have them outputted in the same profile object? If that makes sense? So when I get my sql results back all images associated to a profile will be in the same object? If that's even possible with mySql? Just to mention I'm using node-mysql to make the queries @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister

Comment: You can remove the `GROUP BY`, add an `ORDER BY content_ptr_id`, and loop results in your client processing records in such a way all iamges in records with same `content_ptr_id` are processed in the same profile.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister ah Yeah, that's what I was initially thinking! Want sure if it was possible via sql or not. But how will I manage my limit and offset? Say I want the first 10 venues, it would return duplicated venues because of the photos?

Comment: Maybe `Select Distinct` helps :)

Answer (score 1):

From reading your question, I think you don't have a grasp of how the GROUP BY clause works.

So the short summary of my answer is: learn the fundamentals of the GROUP BY clause.

I will use only a small number of columns to make the explanation easier.

The first problem with your query is that you are not using the group by clause properly - when using a group by clause, all columns that are selected must be either in the group by clause OR be selected with an aggregate function.

Lets suppose these are the only columns you are selecting:
`profile.content_ptr_id`
`profile.body`
`profile.web_site`
`image.id`
`image.content_id`

And the query looked like this:

```
SELECT `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`, `image.id`, `image.content_id`
FROM ...
GROUP BY `profile.content_ptr_id`
```

This query will error out as you did not specify how you want to consolidate multiple rows to one row for `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`, `image.id`, `image.content_id`. The database does not know how you want to consolidate the other columns as you can group, or use aggregate functions such as min(), max(), count(), etc.

So one solution to fix the error raised in the query above would be the following:

```
SELECT `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`, `image.id`, `image.content_id`
FROM ...
GROUP BY `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`, `image.id`, `image.content_id`
```

Here, I put all the columns in the group by clause which makes the query group and select all the unique combinations of `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`, `image.id`, `image.content_id` columns.

Following is an example query which does not have all the columns included in the group by clause:

Lets say, you want to find out how many images there are for each of the profiles. You can use a query such as the following:

```
SELECT `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`, COUNT(`image.id`)
FROM ...
GROUP BY `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`
```

This query lets you find out how many images there are for every unique combination of `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site` columns.

Be aware that in my previous two examples, all the columns that are selected are either included in the group by clause or are selected with an aggregate function. This is a rule all queries need to follow when using the group by clause, otherwise an error will be raised by the database.

Now, lets get onto answering your question:

"Is there a way I can group my results per profile? E.g all images will show in the one profile result?"

I will use the following mock data to explain:

```
profile
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
| content_ptr_id |     body     |   web_site    |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+
|      100       |     body1    |     web1      |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+

image
+--------+-------------+
|   id   |  content_id |
+--------+-------------+
|  iid1  |     100     |
|  iid2  |     100     |
+--------+-------------+
```

Following would be what the result would look like if you don't do a join:

```
SELECT `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`, `image.id`, `image.content_id`
FROM ...

+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------+-------------+
| content_ptr_id |     body     |   web_site    |   id   |  content_id |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------+-------------+
|      100       |     body1    |     web1      |  iid1  |     100     |
|      100       |     body1    |     web1      |  iid2  |     100     |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------+-------------+
```

You can't achieve your objective of grouping your results per profile (combining to only show one line per profile) by grouping by all the columns as the result will be the same:

```
SELECT `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`, `image.id`, `image.content_id`
FROM ...
GROUP BY `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`, `image.id`, `image.content_id`
```

will return

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------+-------------+
| content_ptr_id |     body     |   web_site    |   id   |  content_id |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------+-------------+
|      100       |     body1    |     web1      |  iid1  |     100     |
|      100       |     body1    |     web1      |  iid2  |     100     |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------+-------------+
```

The question you need to answer is how you want to display the non-unique columns you want to combine - in this case `image.id`. You can use count, but this will only return you a number. If you want to display all the text, you can use GROUP_CONCAT() which will concatenate all the values delimited by comma by default. If you use GROUP_CONCAT() the result will look like the following:

```
SELECT `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`, GROUP_CONCAT(`image.id`), GROUP_CONCAT(`image.content_id`)
FROM ...
GROUP BY `profile.content_ptr_id`, `profile.body`, `profile.web_site`
```

This query will return:

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------+
| content_ptr_id |     body     |   web_site    |  GROUP_CONCAT(id)  |  content_id |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------+
|      100       |     body1    |     web1      |     iid1,iid2      |     100     |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

If GROUP_CONCAT() is what you want to use for all the image columns, then go ahead, but doing this for many columns consolidating many rows may make the table less readable. But either way, I would suggest you read some articles to familiarise yourself with how the GROUP BY clause works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `GROUP BY` clause.

I suspect you didn't want to do a GROUP BY operation, given that the expression in the group by is the PRIMARY KEY of the content_profile table.

What is up with all the single quotes? Those are used to enclose string literals, not identifiers.

Thank for sparing us from "scrolling endlessly to the right".

Are you aware that spaces and linebreaks can be included in the SQL text, without altering the meaning of the statement? The parser can easily deal with extra whitespace, and adding the extra whitespace to format the statement can make it much easier for a human reader to decipher.

It's not at all clear why the statement is skipping over the first ten rows, and then returning the next twelve. Very strange.

```
SELECT p.content_ptr_id         AS `profile.content_ptr_id`
     , p.body                   AS `profile.body`
     , p.web_site               AS `profile.web_site`
     , p.email                  AS `profile.email`
     , p.hours                  AS `profile.hours`
     , p.price_range            AS `profile.price_range`
     , p.price_range_high       AS `profile.price_range_high`
     , p.primary_category_id    AS `profile.primary_category_id`
     , p.business_contact_email AS `profile.business_contact_email`
     , p.business_contact_phone AS `profile.business_contact_phone`
     , p.show_in_directory      AS `profile.show_in_directory`
     , i.id                     AS `image.id`
     , i.content_id             AS `image.content_id`
     , i.type                   AS `image.type`
     , i.order                  AS `image.order`
     , i.caption                AS `image.caption`
     , i.author_id              AS `image.author_id`
     , i.image                  AS `image.image`
     , i.link_url               AS `image.link_url`
  FROM `content_profile` p
  LEFT
  JOIN `content_image` i
    ON i.content_id = p.content_ptr_id
 ORDER
    BY p.content_ptr_id
     , i.id
```

Because `content_id` is not unique in the content_image table, duplicate rows from `content_profile` are the expected result.

If your code can't handle the "duplicate" rows, i.e. identifying when the row that was just fetched has the same value for content_ptr_id as the previous row, then your SQL shouldn't do a join operation that creates the duplicated values.